Problem when Training LLM, shape of 3D attn_mask is wrong
I am currently trying to train a LLM using the PyTorch library but i have an Issue which I can not solve. I don't know how to fix this Error. Maybe someone can help me. In the post I will include a screenshot of the error.
This is the code for my training cell:
for epoch in range(1):   
    for batch in train_loader:

        input_ids = batch['input_ids']
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']

        targets = input_ids[:, 1:]
        input_ids = input_ids[:, :-1]
        input_attention_mask = attention_mask[:, :-1].to(torch.float).transpose(0, 1)
        target_attention_mask = attention_mask[:, 1:].to(torch.float).transpose(0, 1)

        input_ids, targets, target_attention_mask, input_attention_mask = input_ids.to(device), targets.to(device), target_attention_mask.to(device), input_attention_mask.to(device)

        logits = model(input_ids, targets, input_attention_mask, target_attention_mask)

        loss = criterion(logits.view(-1, vocabulary_size), targets.view(-1))

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    if epoch % 25 == 0:
        losses = estimate_loss()
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss Train: {losses['train_loader']:.3f}, Loss Validation: {losses['validation_loader']:.3f}")
    if epoch % 250 == 0:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.pth")
        #to load again model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pth"))

this for my forward function:
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class TransformerLanguageModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim=512, num_heads=8, num_layers=8, hidden_dim=2048):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.token_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.position_embedding = nn.Embedding(1023, embedding_dim)
        
        self.encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
                d_model=embedding_dim, 
                nhead=num_heads, 
                dim_feedforward=hidden_dim
            ) for _ in range(num_layers)
        ])


        self.decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(
                d_model=embedding_dim, 
                nhead=num_heads, 
                dim_feedforward=hidden_dim
            ) for _ in range(num_layers)
        ])


    
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, input_ids, targets, input_attention_mask=None, target_attention_mask=None):
        input_token_embeddings = self.token_embedding(input_ids)
        input_positions = torch.arange(0, input_ids.size(1), device=input_ids.device).unsqueeze(0)
        input_position_embeddings = self.position_embedding(input_positions)
        encoder_embeddings = input_token_embeddings + input_position_embeddings
        
        for layer in self.encoder_layers:
            encoder_embeddings = layer(encoder_embeddings, src_key_padding_mask=input_attention_mask)
        
    
        target_token_embeddings = self.token_embedding(targets)
        target_positions = torch.arange(0, targets.size(1), device=targets.device).unsqueeze(0)
        target_position_embeddings = self.position_embedding(target_positions)
        decoder_embeddings = target_token_embeddings + target_position_embeddings

        seq_len = targets.size(1)
        causal_mask = torch.triu(torch.ones(seq_len, seq_len, device=targets.device)).unsqueeze(0)

        for layer in self.decoder_layers:
            decoder_embeddings = layer(decoder_embeddings, encoder_embeddings, tgt_key_padding_mask=target_attention_mask, memory_key_padding_mask=input_attention_mask, tgt_mask=causal_mask)

            
        logits = self.fc_out(decoder_embeddings)
        return logits

This is the error
The shape of teh 3D attn_mask is torch.Size([1, 1023, 1023]), but should be (8184, 32, 32).)

I tried reshaping the attention_mask to fit the dimensions, and I also tried to run the train code without attention_mask as I defined in the forward function, that it should also work without attention_mask. I had no luck with both options. Reshaping did not work as I got different errors and I was not able to reshape it to the correct tensor dimensions. Also when just trying to fit the model without the parameters input_attention_mask and target_attention_mask, the same error as in the screenshot occured. I am a bit clueless to what else to try. I am also a bit confused as attn_mask was never defined in the fist place, only attention_mask, input_attention_mask, and target_attention_mask.
